# MVC 4 Dropdownlist form.submit pass in parameter value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have this dropdown list that I would like it to post back, and pass the id to the controller.  This code as it currently is will post back when I change the drop down, but as you can see, there is a hardcoded value of 3 that I am passing in.  How do I get the SelectList value of the selected item to pass it to the controller?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "PurchaseOrder", new { id = 3 }))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("jobStatuses", (SelectList)null, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
}
```

Comment: Pass the id of what? The selected value of the dropdown? Is this the only control in the view?

Comment: Yes, the selected value of the dropdown.  There are two controls in the view, the other is a list of items.  I am just trying to take the selected value of the dropdown and pass it back to the controller to reload the page and filter the list.

Comment: Why not just use AJAX to post the value and refresh the list? - much better performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "PurchaseOrder", new { id = "" }))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("id", (SelectList)null, new { onchange =  "this.form.submit();" })
}
```

Changing the name of the control to id will pass it through to the id parameter of the controller action